# How to retrieve files from another directory level?

Tags: python, directory, active-directory, filenotfoundexception

For the last few days, I have been trying to figure out how to handle a `FileNotFoundError` in my Python project. It's a Flask app, but the problem should apply for similar directory structures.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
app/
    pdf_report.py
    files/
        icon.png
webapp/
    flask_app.py
    /templates
```

The `pdf_report.py` file has a function that looks like this:

```
def generate_pdf():
    with open("files/icon.png") as file:
        return make_pdf()
```

The problem is that function will not work when I call it from `webapp/flask_app.py`:

```
from pdf_report import generate_pdf
    generate_pdf()
```

That code throws an error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files/icon.png'

Obviously, that's because the Active Directory is `webapp/`, and there isn't a `files/icon.png` filepath in `webapp/`.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an absolute path to your pdf file.

```py
import os

def generate_pdf():
    working_directory = os.getcwd().replace('webapp', 'app')
    file_path = os.path.join(working_directory, 'files/icon.png')
    with open(file_path) as file:
        return make_pdf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add app.config['filepath']='absolute/path/to/files/dir' in config file or **init**.py
then do following:

```
def generate_pdf():
    with open(app.config['filepath']+'/icon.png') as file:
        return make_pdf()
```

Comment: I don't think I can do that. The generate_pdf function is outside of the Flask app context. It's completely outside of the Flask project directory.